# How can I load client certificates from personal store using ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, cryptography, x509certificate, rsacryptoserviceprovider

How can I load client certificates from personal store using ASP.NET?

If it is possible, can I a crypt data with it?

For that I created an application in ASP.NET 2.0 that retrieves all certificates installed in the client certificate store (personal) to create with it a digital signature.

but it does not work , and I don’t know what is the problem

```
// ...
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;

namespace WebApplication4
{
    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        public static string ToHexString(byte[] bytes)
        {
           // ...
        }

        protected void btnSignature_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
            store.Open(OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly);
            X509Certificate2Collection certificates = store.Certificates;

            int a = certificates.Count;

            lbCertCount.Text = System.Convert.ToString(a);

            if (a > 0)
            {
                X509Certificate2 certificate = certificates[1];

                string publicKey = certificate.GetPublicKeyString();
                lbMypublicKey.Text = publicKey + "<br/>";

                // AsymmetricAlgorithm privateKey = certificate.PrivateKey;

                RSACryptoServiceProvider privateKey = certificate.PrivateKey as RSACryptoServiceProvider;

                // test message 
                byte[] buffer = Encoding.Default.GetBytes("Welcome");
                byte[] signature = privateKey.SignData(buffer, new SHA1Managed());
                string me = ToHexString(signature);

                lbSignature.Text = me;


                RSACryptoServiceProvider publicKey1 = certificate.PublicKey.Key as RSACryptoServiceProvider;

                bool verify = publicKey1.VerifyData(buffer, new SHA1Managed(), signature);

                if (verify == true)
                {
                    lbControl.Text = "Signature valid";
                }
                else
                {
                    lbControl.Text = "Signature not Valid";
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to load the visitors certificate or a certificate for a user account on the server?

Comment: I try to load visitors certificate, NB : all  my visitors are in intranet network and all are logged on active directory

Comment: Ok. How do you authenticate your users? Are they impersonated?

Comment: You are a genius, I have just changed the default configuration webconfig by <identity impersonate="true" /> and that's work, thanks

Comment: I'm glad I could help! I've made an answer of my comment if you'd like to mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 2):

For all Googlers:

Add this to your `Web.Config`:

```
<identity impersonate="true" />
```

For more information, see [msdn on impersonation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/72wdk8cc%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you have knocked up this ASP.NET app. as a test harness and it is not actually your intention to write a production application that accesses the personal cert. store on a web server? I haven't studied or tested your code at all but I would check security priviledges in the first instance.  I expect the account under which the ASP.Net worker process is running does not have access to the personal cert. store.

Comment: 1/ you have to know that  i need to load certificate on client  store "personal " not on a web server store

2/ yes right ,   it's  not a production version ,i just testing this code to implementing in  real Application 

3/ what is the  account that asp.net must be ruining  to  load Client certificate ??

Comment: I havn't done anything with the cert store for years, but I believe and it woudl seem to make sense that to access a cert in the personal store you would need to run under the account that imported the cert into said store.  I recommend that you run your test harness in a console app. under the same account you used to import the cert. into the store.